# How to solve the floor function equation $\lfloor2x\rfloor+\lfloor3x\rfloor+\lfloor7x\rfloor=2008$

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

So I was yet again looking on Michael Penn's Youtube channel to see if there were any math equations on his channel that I thought that I might be able to solve when I came across [this](https://youtu.be/E4ONixikb6Q?si=dzkoVPxeVVni2Q2H) member only video of his that I found interesting (don't worry, I also don't have access to it). The equation on the thumbnail was$$\lfloor2x\rfloor+\lfloor3x\rfloor+\lfloor7x\rfloor=2008$$which I thought that I might be able to solve. Here is my attempt at doing so:$$\begin{align}f(x)=\lfloor2x\rfloor&+\lfloor3x\rfloor+\lfloor7x\rfloor=2008\\&\approx\lfloor x\rfloor(2+3+7)\\&=12\lfloor x\rfloor=2008\end{align}$$Now, dividing by $12$ on both sides gets us$$\lfloor x\rfloor=167+\dfrac23\implies\lfloor\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor=\lfloor x\rfloor=167\implies x\in[167,168)$$If you're confused on the last bit, it basically means that $x$ must be a number in a set (let's say set $\mathbb A$ for example) that are all numbers in $\mathbb R$ that are greater than $167$ but are less than $168$, with $167$ included in said set.

Now, let $x=a_{n,k}=167+f(n,k)$ where $f(n,k)=\dfrac{n'}{k'},2\leq n\lt k,3\leq k\require{cancel}\cancel\implies\dfrac{\dfrac{df}{dn}}{\dfrac{df}{dk}}$ however it means that any term $n_\alpha$ and $k_\beta$ where $\alpha,\beta$ are in the set of integers (with $\alpha<\beta$). Now let's have there being a set containing all of the prime numbers. (Let's call this set $\mathbb B$) Starting with $\alpha=1,\beta=2$ (so $n_1=2,k_2=3$) we let $\alpha\longrightarrow \beta-1$, and every time we hit $\alpha=\beta-1$, we let $\beta\mapsto\beta+1$ until $167+\dfrac{n_\alpha}{k_\beta}$ is a solution to $f(x)=2008$, so we have$$a_{1,2}\implies x=167+\dfrac23\implies f(x)=2011$$$$a_{1,3}\implies x=167.4\implies f(x)=2007$$$$a_{2,3}\implies x=167.6\implies f(x)=2010$$$$a_{2,4}\implies x=167+\dfrac37\implies f(x)=2008$$Which is actually our lower limit of the solution, as confirmed by [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=floor%5C%2840%292x%5C%2841%29%2Bfloor%5C%2840%293x%5C%2841%29%2Bfloor%5C%2840%297x%5C%2841%29%3D2008). We can actually find our upper limit by allowing $n$ and $k$ to be non-prime numbers (however in the set of natural numbers this time), while still having $n\leq k-1$, starting with $n=1$, $k=2$:$$f(167.5)=200\color{red}{9}\text{ however }\lim_{x\longrightarrow167.5^-}f(x)=2008$$which means the solution is represented by the inequality $\dfrac{1172}7\leq x\lt\dfrac{335}2$, which implies that our solution set is represented by$$x\in\left[\dfrac{1772}7,167.5\right)$$

---

#### My question

---

Is there anyway I could solve this more quickly, or is this already the most efficient solution possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I absolutely don't understand your notations (and $\approx$ doesn't mean anything), but your solution of $\frac{1172}{7} \leqslant x < \frac{335}{2}$ seems to be the right answer. If you want an other method, here is one. Let us call $(1)$ this equation and $A$ the set of all real solutions. Change your unknown with $y = 42x = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 7 \cdot x$. The equation becomes, $\lfloor y/21 \rfloor + \lfloor y/14 \rfloor + \lfloor y/6 \rfloor = 2008$, let us call this equation $(2)$.

Notice that if $n$ is an integer and $y$ a real number such that $n \leqslant y < n + 1$, and $m > 0$ an integer, we have, $\frac{n}{m} \leqslant \frac{y}{m} < \frac{n + 1}{m}$.
It implies that $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{m} \right\rfloor \leqslant \left\lfloor \frac{y}{m} \right\rfloor$.

Reciprocally, assume that $p$ is an integer such that $\frac{n}{m} < p \leqslant \frac{y}{m}$. Then $p < \frac{n + 1}{m}$ so $n < pm < n + 1$, which is impossible because $pm$ is an integer. It proves the equality $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{m} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{y}{m} \right\rfloor$.

As $n = \lfloor y \rfloor$, it can be rewritten as $\left\lfloor \frac{\lfloor y \rfloor}{m} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{y}{m} \right\rfloor$, for any real number $y$ and any integer number $m > 0$. Using this, we have for all $y$ that $y$ solution of the equation $(2)$ if and only if its floor is.

As $y \mapsto \lfloor y/21 \rfloor + \lfloor y/14 \rfloor + \lfloor y/6 \rfloor$ is an increasing function that tends to $\pm\infty$ when $y \rightarrow \pm\infty$, thus the set $S = \{n \in \mathbb{Z}|n$ is solution of $(2)\}$ is an interval of integers (or empty). Let $S = [\![a,b]\!]$ for $a \leqslant b$ (if $S \neq \emptyset$). The previous statement implies that the set of all real solution of $(2)$ is the interval $I = [a,b + 1[$ (or $\emptyset$ if $S = \emptyset$).

Now, notice that,
$$
\lfloor 7031/21 \rfloor + \lfloor 7031/14 \rfloor + \lfloor 7031/6 \rfloor = 2007, \quad \lfloor 7032/21 \rfloor + \lfloor 7032/14 \rfloor + \lfloor 7032/6 \rfloor = 2008,
$$
$$
\lfloor 7034/21 \rfloor + \lfloor 7034/14 \rfloor + \lfloor 7034/6 \rfloor = 2008, \quad \lfloor 7035/21 \rfloor + \lfloor 7035/14 \rfloor + \lfloor 7035/6 \rfloor = 2009.
$$
Therefore, $S \neq \emptyset$ and $a = 7032$ and $b = 7034$. It implies that $I = [7032,7035[$ so $A = \left[\frac{7032}{42},\frac{7035}{42}\right[ = \left[\frac{1172}{7},\frac{735}{2}\right[$.

Answer (score 3):

The way I would approach it is to observe that in the interval $x \in [0,1)$, the terms $\lfloor 2x \rfloor$, $\lfloor 3x \rfloor$, and $\lfloor 7x \rfloor$ are constant in each subinterval $x \in [\frac{k}{42}, \frac{k+1}{42})$ for each fixed nonnegative integer $k \in \{0, 1, \ldots, 41\}$.  For instance, when $k = 25$, then $x \in [\frac{25}{42}, \frac{26}{42})$ satisfies $\lfloor 2x \rfloor = 1$, $\lfloor 3x \rfloor = 1$, and $\lfloor 7x \rfloor = 4$.

So let us write $$x = n + \frac{k}{42}, \quad n \in \mathbb Z,$$ hence $$\begin{align}
f(x) &= \lfloor 2x \rfloor + \lfloor 3x \rfloor + \lfloor 7x \rfloor \\
&= 2n + 3n + 7n + \left\lfloor \frac{k}{21}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{k}{14}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{k}{6}\right\rfloor \\
&= 12n + \left\lfloor \frac{k}{21}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{k}{14}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{k}{6}\right\rfloor.
\end{align}$$
Noting that $k \le 41$, then $$0 \le \lfloor k/21 \rfloor \le 1, \quad 0 \le \lfloor k/14 \rfloor \le 2, \quad 0 \le \lfloor k/6 \rfloor \le 6.$$  So the sum of these terms is bounded below by $0$ and above by $9$; hence $f(x) = 2008$ implies $$166 < \frac{2008 - 9}{12} \le n \le \frac{2008}{12} < 168.$$  Since $n$ is an integer, we require $n = 167$, which in turn means that $k$ must satisfy $$\left\lfloor \frac{k}{21}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{k}{14}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{k}{6}\right\rfloor = 2008 - 12(167) = 4.$$  If the first term equals $1$, i.e. $k \ge 21$, then the second term is at least $1$ and the third term is at least $3$, which will sum to $5$.  So $k \le 20$.  So we know the first term must be zero.  Then the second term is at most $1$ (since $k \le 20$); so the third term must be at least $3$, which implies $k \ge 18$.  This leaves just three candidates which are easily checked; all of them give a sum of $0 + 1 + 3 = 4$.  Consequently, the solution set corresponds to

$$x \in \left[167 + \frac{18}{42}, 167 + \frac{21}{42}\right) = \left[\frac{1172}{7}, \frac{335}{2}\right).$$

Answer (score 2):

Since

$$\lfloor 2x \rfloor \le  2x <  \lfloor 2x \rfloor+1$$
$$\lfloor 3x \rfloor \le  3x <  \lfloor 3x \rfloor+1$$
$$\lfloor 7x \rfloor \le  7x <  \lfloor 7x \rfloor+1$$

Adding and simplifying, we get

\begin{equation}
    2008 \le 12x < 2011
\end{equation}

And, so...

$$167\frac 13 \le x < 167\frac{7}{12}$$

This answer is easily verified.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lfloor\mathrm{2}{x}\rfloor+\lfloor\mathrm{3}{x}\rfloor+\lfloor\mathrm{7}{x}\rfloor=\mathrm{2008} \\ $$
$$\lfloor{px}\rfloor=\left[\lceil\frac{\mathrm{2008}{p}}{\mathrm{12}}\rceil;\lfloor\frac{\mathrm{2011}{p}}{\mathrm{12}}\rfloor\right] \\ $$
$$\lfloor\mathrm{2}{x}\rfloor=\mathrm{335},\:\lfloor\mathrm{3}{x}\rfloor=\mathrm{502} \\ $$
$$\lfloor\mathrm{7}{x}\rfloor=\left[\mathrm{1172};\mathrm{1173}\right] \\ $$
$$\lfloor\mathrm{7}{x}\rfloor=\mathrm{2008}−\lfloor\mathrm{2}{x}\rfloor−\lfloor\mathrm{3}{x}\rfloor \\ $$
$$\lfloor\mathrm{7}{x}\rfloor=\mathrm{1171}\notin\left[\mathrm{1172};\left[\mathrm{1173}\right]\right. \\ $$
$$\left[{NO}\:{SOLUTION}\right] \\ $$

Comment: Overall this is a good answer imo, since there's some thought into how this equation could have no solution. However, you should realize that IMHO $x=\frac{[2008;2011)}{12}$ shouldn't necessarily imply that $\lfloor2x\rfloor=335,\lfloor3x\rfloor=502,\lfloor7x\rfloor=[1172;1173]$. Would you please be able to clarify your method of getting how you got that exactly?

Comment: Got which one...?

Comment: All 3 of the equations

Comment: Sorry for my bad English...

Comment: I multiply the x range value with 2,3,and 7 to get range value of integer 2x,3x,7x

Comment: Thanks for your advice.,I have modified my

Answer (score 1):

$$\lfloor 2x \rfloor + \lfloor 3x \rfloor + \lfloor 7x \rfloor =2008$$
Let $a=\lfloor 2x \rfloor$ where $a \leq 2x < a+1$.

Let $b=\lfloor 3x \rfloor$ where $b \leq 3x < b+1$.

Let $c=\lfloor 7x \rfloor$ where $c \leq 7x < c+1$.

$$a+b+c=2008$$

$$a>2x-1$$
$$b>3x-1$$
$$c>7x-1$$

$$a \leq 2x$$
$$b \leq 3x$$
$$c \leq 7x$$

$$2x-1 + 3x-1 + 7x-1 <2008$$
$$12x<2011$$
$$x< \frac{2011}{12}$$

$$2x + 3x + 7x \geq 2008$$
$$ x \geq \frac{2008}{12} $$

$$167\frac{1}{3} \leq x < 167 \frac{7}{12}$$